# Pyside QTableWidget - adding new row with new buttons alters styling from unknown source

Tags: python, qt, styling, pyside2

I'm working in Python 3 with Pyside2, Win10.

Have a QTableWidget , row with buttons.
When I update the table (create new row and add new buttons) those buttons get different styling - looks like bold or bigger font - see below.
I tried to localize where is the hidden styling but with no success.

Anybody can help with that?

Below you see first line is normal font, but for unknown reason second (new row) is bigger.
Both lines are generated same way, same code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXCbD.png)

QT is very nice having all these styling options, but it seems some are hidden and hard to fix?

Tried ChatGPT - is clueless.

Tried QT documentations , QFont attributes and finding all parents stylesheet with no luck:

font (last row button):
PySide2.QtGui.QFont.Style.StyleNormal
weight:50
pizel size:-1
bold: False

Also I tried to do mytablewidget.clearSelection() but didn't change anything.

The only stylesheet I define for main window is same for all buttons, no bold font or special size:

```
QWidget {font-family:'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,DejaVu }
QFrame {border:none;}
QTabBar {background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);}
QPushButton {background-color:#ddd; border-style: solid;   border-width: 1px; border-color: #aaa; padding:5px; margin:5px;min-width:32px;}
QPushButton:hover {background-color:#eee;   border-width: 1px; border-color: green;}
QPushButton:pressed {background-color:lightgreen;   border-width: 1px; border-color: green;}
QComboBox {background-color:white; border-style: solid;  border-width: 1px; border-color: #aaa; padding:5px; margin:5px;}
QComboBox:item { selection-background-color: lightgreen; }
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {background-color:white;selection-background-color: lightgreen;border-style: solid;  border-width: 1px; }
QLineEdit {background-color:white; border-style: solid;  border-width: 1px; border-color: #aaa; padding:5px; margin:5px;}
QAbsractScrollArea {border-style:none}
QTableView  {border-style:none}
QAbstractItemView {border-style:none}
QHeaderView {border-style:none}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also note that setting a font for all widgets in stylesheets is a bit pointless, just set it for the application (or the parent window) using `setFont()`.

Comment: This may be not easy to make reproducible example - this is not a small project and I actually do kind of framework (I extended QTableWidget with methods to accept "descriptive" dictionaries to generate UI elements like Buttons or Labels) over Pyside to have it more automatic to generate GUI. I've checked I do not add or update styles anywhere, and after update do not see font or buttons to have different attributes, or widget.styleSheet(), however they do look different like on the image linked.

Comment: What is happening is I create rows on initial "update table" method and later when I provide dict with updated button structure I run again the same method - if there is a new row I create a new row and new widgets inside exact same way as on the init creation. I was thinking some hidden option of Focus or Selection maybe is run automatically for some reason, but clearing selection and focus didn't help.

Comment: Unfortunately, without any context and a basic MRE to start with, it's not possible to help you. The cause may be somewhere in your code, or it can even be a bug, but without knowing the *specific* details of the case, we have nothing to work with.

Comment: Thanks for analyzing anyway. Tracking this will take some time and I need to focus on more important features then style itself, hopefully will come back to this issue later.

Answer (score 0):

After switching to Python 3.11 and Pyside6 the issue does not exist any more.

Assuming this was a UI glitch of old Pyside2 and moving to newer version is recommended.

Simply replacing Pyside2 with PySide6 keyword in few places  - easy.